# I dont understand why a hash is being printed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to learn ruby on rails right now.
I made this site where users can create a match for a 4 player game and assign it to a league.
I'm then displaying the scores in a table.
I'm using hashes for it like this.
This is my controller method for leagues index:

```
def index
    if signed_in?
        @leagues = League.all
        @users = User.all
        @matches = Match.all

        @league_scores=Hash.new(0)

        @scores = Hash.new(0)

        @leagues.each do |league|

            @scores.clear

            @matches.each do |match|
                if match.league_id==league.id
                    @scores[match.player_1_id]+=match.player_1_score
                    @scores[match.player_2_id]+=match.player_2_score
                    @scores[match.player_3_id]+=match.player_3_score
                    @scores[match.player_4_id]+=match.player_4_score
                end
            end

            @league_scores[league.id]=@scores.deep_dup.delete_if {|key, value| value == 0 }
        end
    else
        restrict_access
    end
end
```

And this is the part of the html file:

```
 <div class="p-2">

                    <div class="row border bg-light">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">Gracz</div>
                        <div class="col-sm">Suma wyników</div>
                    </div>

                    <%= @league_scores[league.id].each_key do |key| %>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-4 border bg-light"><%= User.find(key).email%>/div>
                            <div class="col-sm"><%= @league_scores[league.id][key] %></div>
                        </div>
                    <%end%>

                </div>
```

Thr problem i'm having is that after it prints the results it also puts the whole hash at the end like this:
[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Er0rl.png)

> {1=>5, 2=>305, 3=>405, 4=>105, 5=>200}

And i just don't understand why. I have a feeling that i'm doing something wrong in the controller when i'm copying the hash but i don't know how to fix this.
Can someone explain what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please add all information into the post, including your result. Links to resources can get lost

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because `=` you put in:

```
<%= @league_scores[league.id].each_key do |key| %>
```

It causes the return value of this call put in output html. You should have this instead:

```
<% @league_scores[league.id].each_key do |key| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `<%=`, it means that you want to display the result.

In your case, you display the result of the `each_key` loop, which returns the hash you see.

In the process, you also output the table as expected and that's why you see it also.

So, what you want to do is just use `<%` instead of `<%=`. That way, you output anything that you render in your code - but you don't render the actual result value of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Consider these two syntaxes. `code` is some ruby code

`<%= code %>`: The object which gets returned after the execution of `code` gets printed.

`<% code %>`: The `code` is only executed in this case.

In your case if you remove the `=` from the 
`<%= @league_scores[league.id].each_key do |key| %>`,

only execution takes place and the hash is not printed.